# PHP Compress Image with Lossy/Lossless

Tags: php

How can I, using PHP, compress an image with Lossy/Lossless compression in a similar way that these two sites compress them:

https://compressor.io/ and https://kraken.io/web-interface

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

These websites don't compress images using **PHP** and you can't get a similar result by using **PHP** - They use different compression tools or plugins written specially to compress images.

To compress a **PNG**, the best solution is [pngquant](http://pngquant.org/php.html), but you have to **install** it on your server to use it with **PHP**.

Also, [here is the list of tools](http://addyosmani.com/blog/image-optimization-tools/) you can check, about the compression of different type of images.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can with this PHP API: [PHP API for images](https://github.com/kraken-io/kraken-php#lossy-optimization)

It's a set of tools for managing images where lossy optimization is included.